# OSX Yosemite - invalid characters in path

Tags: macos, git, bash, path, homebrew

I'm having trouble installing Homebrew, and it looks like the problem (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError) error message) is due to a fault in my PATH. when I run echo $PATH, I get the following (be sure to scroll to the far right in the code block below to see the fault):

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/subversion/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH:PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH:export PATH��:/usr/local/git/bin
```

I have no idea where those strange characters just before the /usr/local/git/bin path are coming from. I'm using bash (tried zshell, same problem). I can't find where this coming from. my .bash_profile file looks clean, too.

Comment: Whatever puts them there has another error as well -- the `export` is a (usually unnecessary) part of the command, not part of the value. The value suggests you installed `git` locally when this happened. There are multiple other errors as well, where you have `PATH=` and `$PATH` as part of the value. But we can't troubleshoot without access to your files. Did you edit your `.bashrc` manually? What about `.profile`?

Comment: would I get that by editing the ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile files? .bashrc is blank, and the .bash_profile has a bunch of stuff modified by macports. Also, how can I make these files available for viewing?

Comment: You will need to establish where the erroneous changes to your PATH are being made.  Since you're using `bash`, I suggest using: `bash -x -l` (followed by `exit`) to see exactly what happens when you log in.  It looks like there are perhaps 5 attempts in the code to set the PATH, and 4 of them are erroneous.  It is more than a little weird what you are seeing, though.  You might also try `echo "$PATH" | od -c` which would show you what byte values the erroneous characters have.

Comment: Another thing to check: launch AppleScript Editor from the Finder or Dock (not using a shell in any way), enter the script `do shell script "env"`, and click Run. This will show the environment inherited from `launchd` with any influence from any shell initialization scripts. See if the problem is exhibited there, too.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I ran the 'bash -x -1' command (not sure how to follow it with 'exit' though). I did get a lot of results, but I'm not sure how to interpret these results. Is there some way for me to post the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine your `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, and `~/.bashrc` files.  It is also possible that these values are being set in `/etc/profile` or other system-wide files, but the nature of the errors is such that I would assume they are the result of your own manual edits of your personal files.  You're the best judge to decide what you may have changed and when.

Look for entries such as the following:

```
 PATH='/usr/local/share/python:$PATH'
 PATH='PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH'
 PATH='export PATH��:/usr/local/git/bin'
```

They should instead look like

```
 PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH
 PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH
 PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin
 # Not strictly necessary -- PATH is already exported
 export PATH
```

See a pattern?  These all add a value to `PATH` by setting it to `prefix:$PATH` or `$PATH:suffix` where the new prefix or suffix is the directory where you have installed a local package.  Whether the new value should be a prefix or a suffix is probably of little consequence -- except if you are trying to override a system version (say, your `/usr/local/git` is installed because `/usr/bin/git` is too old -- then, it's important that your `local` version comes first in the `PATH`).  There is also a minuscule speed difference the first time you run a command; the shell has to look in more places before finding it if it's at the end of the `PATH`.

The difference in quoting is significant -- `PATH=$PATH:suffix` expands to the old value of `PATH` with `:suffix` added on, whereas `PATH='$PATH:suffix'` replaces the old value of `PATH` with the literal string `$PATH` with `:suffix` added on.  You're lucky none of this has ended up replacing your original `PATH` completely, which would render your shell by and large inoperable (at least until you discover that you have to use `/bin/ls` instead of just `ls`).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I guess my confusion (since I'm quite new to all of this) is that there are so many files that can set this path variable. Is there a pecking order? Because I've looked at ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile, and ~/.bashrc, and none of these files reference anything related to git.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler's comment has a good debugging method. In the end, if you cannot figure out where the erroneous values come from, you could just override them in your own startup file (`.bashrc` should cover most bases).

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I was finally able to get past the problem by overriding this in the '.bashrc' file. I'm disappointed that I didn't have more time to explore @JonathanLeffler's troubleshooting tips. I did spend some time with these, and while I didn't find the root cause of the problem, I did learn more about how this works. Next time, I'll be more careful with my experiments.

Comment: I'm still stumped, still having problems and could really use some help, considering that I have very little experience in this area. I am still seeing invalid characters in my path, causing things like Home Brew to fail. I've spent hours trying to follow the suggestions given, but I lack the background to really understand what I'm seeing. Something is adding to my path beyond the ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile, and ~/.bashrc files. Should I open a new question? I can provide additional info through Pastebin if needed. At this point, I'm at my wits end, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: after digging around some more, it seems that the OS X path_helper is causing my problem. In my /private/etc/profile file, all I had was two if statements which seemed to decide whether to use path_helper or bashrc. I removed that code (making the profile file blank). I now, no longer have the invalid characters in my path, and Brew runs fine now. I can share the code I removed from my profile file if that would help.

Comment: Feel free to post that as a separate answer.