# OS X 10.10 - path_helper causing invalid characters in path?

Tags: macos, bash, path

In an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097698/osx-yosemite-invalid-characters-in-path), I had problems with invalid/non-ASCII characters in my path statement. Thanks to some helpful answers, I was able to fix most of the problem, but I still need some help.

To resolve the problem, I made changes to my `/private/etc/profile` file and removed these lines:

```
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
    [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

Once I removed those lines, the corrupted characters in my path went away. So, I suspect that `path_helper` was picking up some invalid characters and inserting them in my Path. But, I'm very new to all of this, so I'm not sure how to go about investigating how `path_helper` modifies my path?

Answer (score 1):

`path_helper` is returning a line of shell code that is being executed with `eval`.

So if you want to see what it is doing just run it (either by hand or in your `profile` script) **without** the `eval` and backticks.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the files in **/etc/paths.d** if they contain any invalid (maybe invisible) character. For me it helped to do a "**wc ***" in that directory. That lists in the first column the number of lines in each file. I had some files without trailing newline. After adding a newline to the end of each file it worked. I had to call

```
PATH=''
eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
```

To make the change effective.

I could not find a pattern how to force a specific invalid pattern into the path, but the number of errors and the position of errors did not directly relate to the order of my files or the number of files with missing newline.